# Set Default Level option for Linux tree command

Tags: linux, macos, treeview

Is there any way to set a default -L option when running the tree command?  For example, instead for typing

```
tree -L 2
```

I would rather type just

```
tree
```

Currently the default "tree" command shows all nested levels, but I typically want to see only 2 levels deep.  I would still want the option to override the default if I wanted to see something other than 2 levels deep, i.e.

```
tree -L 3
```

Comment: How about `alias tree='tree -L 2'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Biffen above, adding an alias does it.